# Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'KLT_tracks'

Tags: matlab

I use matlab for tracking with opticalflow.
The original function(KLT_tracks()) was in C language,so I changed it to matlab,
I have built Kly_tracks.mexw64 file and got it in the right place,but when calling the function,the command line stopped with

```
Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'KLT_tracks' 
The closest match is: kLT_tracks
in E:\lab_source\CODE\kLT_tracks.mexw64
```

I don't know how to deal with it.

==================================

I solve the problem by using the command:

```
mex -output KLT KLT_tracks.c
```

instead of

```
mex  KLT_tracks.c
```

to change the default name,KLT_tracks.mexw64 to KLT.mexw64,
I still don't why.

Comment: Are you sure you got all the upper/lower-cases right?

Answer (score 1):

If `E:\lab_source\CODE\` is in your MATLAB path or is your current directory, the most likely explanation is that you have typed `KLT_tracks()` whereas your MATLAB Function is called `kLT_tracks`, which is not the same thing. Remember that MATLAB is case-sensitive, as the error message points out.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox includes the [vision.PointTracker](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.pointtracker-class.html) object, which implements the KLT algorithm.  That may save you the trouble.